# INSERT INTO in Spring Boot (Cannot Insert a list into my table in spring boot using jpa nativeQuery)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, bulkinsert

I am having trouble inserting a list (bulk-insert) into my Myslq DB using JPA in spring boot application:

i have my Query as:

[image]

here my :listVal is a string coming from setAll() method and it contains a string value as: "(15,2083),(15,2084),(15,2085),(15,2086),(15,2087),(15,2088),(15,2089),(15,2090),(15,2091),(15,2092)" and when i run the server, i get error saying:

[image: the Error]

can anyone give some suggection about how to fix this problem, Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: That is not a list that is a single string. Just pass the list of strings, hibernate will do the rest.

Comment: do you mean like:   List<String> listVal ?

Comment: that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: tried it, didn't work.i have my string list as: ["(1,1)","(1,2)","(1,3)"] where each element in the list represents a row in the DB

Comment: Please post code as code (including tghe error) as what you currently have (images) is totally unreadable. ANd what doesn't work when passing the list? One thing is you are passing a single value, you should be passing a list of lists, with each list containing 2 elements.

Comment: this is how i construct my list and send it to repository where i write my above query List<String> st = new ArrayList<>(0);
        String values = "";
        values = "(" + trainingId + "," + (initialTicketId++) + ")";
        st.add(values);
        for (int i = 0; i < labelCount; i++) {
            values = values + "(" + trainingId + "," + (initialTicketId++) + ")";
            st.add(values);
        }
        this.repository.setAll(st);

Comment: As stated that is wrong, you should be passing a list of lists. You shouldn't be formatting the content yourself, you should be passing the actual values (which are probably longs or ints). And plase don't post code as comments as that is unreadable as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239302/discussion-between-ashraf-yawar-and-m-deinum).

Comment: @M.Deinum I've tried what you say, but it is NOT posible. Even with List<List<Integer>>, for example: [ [1, 2],  [2, 2],  [4, 2] ]. Hibernate: INSERT INTO user_role (id_user, id_role) VALUES ( ?,  ?,  ? ). It tries there are 3 values instead of 2. But what I am trying is to insert 3 rows. It gives the following error: **ERROR: INSERT tiene más expresiones que columnas de destino** . I think the only way to pass a collection in a native query is in **IN clause** .